# Post Request / Cookie implementation triggers file download on Safari / Iphone 13 (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iphone, cookies

### Configuration

I'm on a Rails app, I use a POST request to trigger an action from a CookiesController. Nothing fancy but on the latest iPhones using Safari, this triggers a file download invite and I can't understand why.

Here is the code used.

#### cookie_form.html.erb

```
<form action="<%= cookies_path %>" method="post" data-turbolinks="false">
          <%= hidden_field_tag "authenticity_token", form_authenticity_token %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag "cookie_accept", "true" %>
          <button type="submit" style="all:unset;">
            <div class="v_button_primary v_button__cookie">
              <%= t('showcase.shared.button.accept') %>
              <%= media_tag "images/arrow-white-right.png", alt: "icon-btn" %>
            </div>
          </button>
        </form>
```

#### routes.rb

```rb
# Cookies
  resources :cookies, only: [:create]
```

#### CookiesController.rb

```rb
class CookiesController < ApplicationController

    def create
      if params[:cookie_accept] == "true"
        cookies.permanent[:cookie_policy] = 'accepted'
        head :no_content
      elsif params[:legal_accept] == "true"
        session[:legal_informations] = 'accepted'
        head :no_content
      else
        head :bad_request
      end
    end
  end
```

Then I have some logic in the ApplicationController to check for the cookies before_action and update an instance variable which shows or hides the cookie modal for example.
As said, nothing fancy.

However, this triggers [this behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCerx.png)

I don't understand what's the issue here and why it triggers this behaviour, because the header is set to "no content", any ideas?